# If $t \leq s$ and $t \neq s$, why $t' \land s \neq 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra

In boolean algebra, why if $t \leq s$ and $t \neq s$, why $t' \land s \neq 0$, where ' is the complement. I see it if I use that all boolean algebras are $\{0,1\}^n$ but I want to have a proof using only the axioms.

Comment: It is not true that all Boolean algebras are $\{0,1\}^n$, for some natural $n$. That is the case for **finite** Boolean algebras. In general, it isn't even the case that any Boolean algebra is of the type $\{0,1\}^X$ for some (finite or infinite) set $X$: take, for example the [algebra of finite-cofinite subsets of a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Boolean_algebras). A simple reasoning based on Cantor's theorem on cardinals allows to conclude that the Boolean algebra of finite-cofinite subsets of a countably infinite set doesn't have that shape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$s=1\wedge s=(t\vee t')\wedge s=(t\wedge s)\vee(t'\wedge s).$$ Now $t\leq s$ means $t\wedge s=t$.  So, if $t'\wedge s$ were $0$, we would get $$s=t\vee 0=t$$ which is a contradiction.